# Builds fine but error while server deployment : XML issue

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I trying to create a simple web service and following errors were occurred while I was trying to run it, in `Tomcat 7` with `spring-webmvc-4.2.4`

### Errors:

> Description   Resource Path Location Type cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The
>   matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for
>   element 'context:component-scan'. mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml  /example/src/main/SpringMVC/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF line 12 XML Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.  mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml  /example/src/main/SpringMVC/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF line 14 XML Problem

### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.2.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.2.4 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_2_4.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.arpit.java2blog</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <type>bundle</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Also POM is having following warring.

> No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.

**springrest-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.arpit.java2blog.controller" />

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
 <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[image: Error log]

Comment: can you show your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`?

Comment: added. please check.

Comment: @mars Can you post your web.xml as well?

Answer (score 1):

In your `pom.xml` you are using `Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE` as:

```
 <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
 </properties>
```

And in your `springrest-servlet.xml` you are referring to `Spring 3.x` DTD.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

Replace your DTD with Spring 4.x schemas as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
```